# How to disable require in multiple inputs and enable the other input in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, input

How to disable `require` in inputs with `name = "item_name"`,`name="description"` and `name="quantity"`    when i click purpose and enable the `require` in purpose `textarea` by using javascript.

Edit: What I really mean is when i submit the form by clicking ADD, only the `input` with name `item_name` `description` `quantity` are required and When I submit the form by clicking Purpose, the `textarea` will be the one who is required

Here is my code:

```
<form action="../function/add_item.php" method="post">

<input id="autocomplete" name="item_name" placeholder="Item Name" required>
<input type="text" name="description"  placeholder="Description placeholder="Quantity"" required>
<input type="number" name="quantity" required>

<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">ADD</button>

<textarea placeholder="Purpose (e.g. Office Use)" name="purpose" required></textarea>

<button name="purpose" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Purpose</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe it's easier to change layout?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking, what are you trying to achieve overall?

Comment: So you want a button that will toggle between `item_name` and `description` no longer required and `purpose` required?

Comment: You have a few errors in your html I'm going to assume the `placeholder="Quantity""` is a typo but a button `type="purpose"` is not a valid html element.

Comment: I already edited my html. when i click the ADD button, the input with  names `item_name` `description` `quantity` will be required and when I click the Purpose button the textarea `purpose` will be required.

Comment: clear your question. you want to toggle required `on and off` with clicking buttons?

Comment: You mean you want to enable `required` attribute on `textarea` when you click `purpose` button and enable `required` on `item_name`, `description` and `quantity` when you click `submit` button?

Comment: What I really mean is when i submit the form by clicking ADD, only the inputs with name `item_name` `description` `quantity` are required and When I submit the form by clicking Purpose, the `textarea` will be the one who is required.

Comment: I got your point already and submitted an answer. You can check it out.

Comment: I added an answer with snippet, you can try it if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is the code you might be looking for:

```
$(function() {
    $('[type=submit]').on('click', function() {
        if($(this).attr('name') == 'submit') {
            $('[name=item_name], [name=description], [name=quantity]').attr('required', 'required');
            $('[name=purpose]').removeAttr('required');
        } else if($(this).attr('name') == 'purpose') {
            $('[name=purpose]').attr('required', 'required');
            $('[name=item_name], [name=description], [name=quantity]').removeAttr('required');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: yes. this is the code I'am looking for. Thank you and sorry for confusions.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` to your button

```
<button id="purpose" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Purpose</button>
```

Then

```
$(function() {
    $('#purpose').click(function() {
        $('#item_name').removeAttr('required');​​​​​
        $('#description').removeAttr('required');​​​​​
        $('#quantity').removeAttr('required');​​​​​
        $('textarea').attr('required','1');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I just added up some javascript and add `id's`

```js
document.getElementById('purpose').onclick = function() {

    document.getElementById("name").required=false;
    document.getElementById("des").required=false;
    document.getElementById("qnt").required=false;
}
```

```html
<form action="../function/add_item.php" method="post">
<input id="name" name="item_name" placeholder="Item Name" required>
<input id="des" type="text" name="description"  placeholder="Description placeholder="Quantity"" required>
<input id="qnt" type="number" name="quantity" required>

<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">ADD</button>
<textarea placeholder="Purpose (e.g. Office Use)" name="purpose" required></textarea>

<button id="purpose" name="purpose" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Purpose</button>
</form>
```